# Android: что за виджет?

Tags: java, android, виджет

Как называется виджет и может кто знает, где посмотреть на готовые библиотеки похожие на указанный пример?

[Ссылка на видео](https://youtu.be/FBeG8CzglaE)

Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смею предположить ,что это `ProgressBar` с кастомным `ProgressDrawable`, и меняющейся в зависимости от текущего прогресса кнопкой

Comment: его двигать можно (на видео)

Comment: А для iOS подскажите? С андроидом разобрался.

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос по `iOS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это Seekbar, урок вам [вот](http://www.edumobile.org/android/seek-bar-example/), [тут похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581602/android-how-to-implement-horizontal-step-progress-bar)

open-source тут - https://github.com/karabaralex/android-comboseekbar

Comment: Тогда каким образом он реализован (на видео в вопросе)?
Получается что слева минимум 0, по центру 50, справа 100 (количество нужно для плавности)
При любом значении от 1 до 24 у него условие - вернуть на 0, при 25 до 49 - вернуть 50 итп?

Comment: Да, у тебя 3 значения поэтому, 0-50-100

Comment: Спасибо, принцип понял!

Comment: А для iOS подскажите? С андроидом разобрался.

Comment: Используйте UISlider